# Error to load ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

Hi I have an error of importing ng2-bootstrap, this is the error,Hi I have an error of importing ng2-bootstrap, this is the error,Hi I have an error of importing ng2-bootstrap, this is the error:

```
http://localhost:3002/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js 404 (Not Found)
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
Error loading http://localhost:3002/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js as "ng2-bootstrap" from http://localhost:3002/app/schedules/schedule-list.component.js
```

heres the systmjs.config.js:

```
/**
* System configuration for Angular 2 samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
*/
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        'jquery': 'npm:jquery/',
        'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',

        'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
        'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
        'symbol-observable': 'npm:symbol-observable'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'symbol-observable': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
});
 })(this);
```

package.json

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "name": "scheduler",
```

"author": "Chris Sakellarios",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "https://github.com/chsakell/angular2-features",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",

```
"jquery": "^3.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.13.1",
"moment": "^2.13.0",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.5",
"ng2-slim-loading-bar": "1.5.1",

"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"del": "^2.2.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
"jquery": "^3.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.0",
"typescript": "2.0.2",
"typings": "^1.3.2",
"tslint": "^3.10.2"
 },
 "scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite --baseDir ./app --port 8000\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"typings": "typings"
}
}
```

Comment: You have wrong url, and therefor 404 result code.

Comment: thank u for ur answer but where??

Comment: import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';  this is my import in schedule-list.component.js

Comment: so what do you think this code is doing? Or what is 'ng2-bootstrap' in the import statement?

Comment: in your paths :  'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js',

Comment: node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js do not exist

Answer (score 0):

In your path object :

```
'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

In your packages object :

```
'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

Comment: thank u ser..i did what u mentioned above but it didnt work

Comment: take a look above

Comment: try 'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js' without the bundles

Answer (score 0):

`ng-2 bootstrap`: this package is deprecated and it is renamed to `ngx-bootstrap`.

Try installing `ngx-bootstrap` using npm.

```
npm i ngx-bootstrap --save
```